# hadoop: having more than one reducers under pseudo distributed environment?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am newbie to hadoop. I have successfully configured a hadoop setup in pseudo distributed mode. I want to have multiple reducers with the option `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=2` (with hadoop-streaming). however there's still only one reducer.

according to Google I'm sure that mapred.LocalJobRunner limits number of reducers to 1. But I wonder is there any workaround to have more reducers?

**my hadoop configuration files:**

```
[admin@localhost string-count-hadoop]$ cat ~/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/core-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/admin/hadoop-data/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>



[admin@localhost string-count-hadoop]$ cat ~/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/mapred-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property>
</configuration>



[admin@localhost string-count-hadoop]$ cat ~/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/hdfs-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/admin/hadoop-data/name</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/admin/hadoop-data/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

**the way I start job:**

```
[admin@localhost string-count-hadoop]$ cat hadoop-startjob.sh 
#!/bin/sh

~/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop jar ~/hadoop-1.1.2/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar \
        -D mapred.job.name=string-count \
        -D mapred.reduce.tasks=2 \
        -mapper  mapper  \
        -file    mapper  \
        -reducer reducer \
        -file    reducer \
        -input   $1      \
        -output  $2

[admin@localhost string-count-hadoop]$ ./hadoop-startjob.sh /z/programming/testdata/items_sequence /z/output
packageJobJar: [mapper, reducer] [] /tmp/streamjob837249979139287589.jar tmpDir=null
13/07/17 20:21:10 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/07/17 20:21:10 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/07/17 20:21:10 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/07/17 20:21:11 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: LocalJobRunner does not support symlinking into current working dir.
...
...
```

Comment: Are you using HDFS or Local file system?

Comment: @JtheRocker, using HDFS.

Comment: Then why are you using LocalJobRunner?

Comment: Please check your configuration files.

Comment: Can you edit your question and state how are you executing your job from the terminal?

Comment: Please share your configuration files - core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml too.

Comment: Can you also share your full invocation line

Comment: @JtheRocker, I posted all configs. `hadoop dfs -ls /` shows my linux root direcory (just like `ls -l`). is that right?

Comment: Please also edit and put how you execute the job (jar).

Comment: Are you able to see the hdfs content when issuing this - hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/ ?  please notice there is an extra /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying core-site.xml's property

```
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
```

to,

```
<property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
 </property>
```

Put an extra **/ after 9000** and restart all the daemons.

Comment: at last I modified conf/masters and conf/slaves from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and made it work. still thanks for your help.